# zend framework 2 how disable multiple errors messages of validator

Tags: forms, validation, syntax-error, messaging, zend-framework2

I am trying to de that the EmailValidator class return me only one error messages.
In other forums I have seen that in ZF1 only is possible make it extending the Validator class.

Anybody know if in ZF2 there is a more easy way for make it?

This is my code for if anyone it help, in this I call setMessages method for overwrite the default messagestemplate, but not works.

```
    $form    = new ParticipantForm();
    $mailInput = new Input('mail');
    $validator = new ValidatorEmailAddres();
    $validator->setMessages(
            array(
                    ValidatorHostName::UNKNOWN_TLD => 'hola'
            )
    );
    $mailInput->getValidatorChain()->addValidator($validator);
    $mailInputFilter = new InputFilter();
    $mailInputFilter->add($mailInput);   
    $form->setInputFilter($mailInputFilter);
    $form->setData($_POST);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$validator = new \Zend\Validator\EmailAddres();
$validator->setMessage('something broke bla');
```

or to set a specific message:

```
$validator = new \Zend\Validator\EmailAddres();
$validator->setMessage('something broke bla', \Zend\Validator\EmailAddres::LENGTH_EXCEEDED);
```